# C# Can I emulate a button pressing in form of a process from another process?

Tags: c#, cucumber

For example I got a WinForm with a buttons on it. Is it possible to press this button from another process? I want to make something like Webrat virtual browser for Cucumber  testing framework but for desktop applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wanna have a look at the pretty new framework by Microsoft: [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163288.aspx)and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx).

This can do WPF very well but works with WinForm as well.

Answer (score 0):

Due to all WinForms controls are wrapper around Win32 controls, you can use Spy++ tool for fetching unmanaged handle of underlied controls (buttons, textboxes etc) via text properties and other signs, and next, use native win32 calls to send custom events to this controls like MouseClick, MouseMove, etc. Consider http://pinvoke.net to more precise info about P/Invoke technique in C#.